# TServerSocket: How check if a specific client on ListView still is connected before send message?

Tags: sockets, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a `Timer` and want send a message to each client of `ListView` to determine a ping time for example. Then i have this following code:

```
procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  try
    for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.count - 1 do
    begin
      ListView1.Items.Item[i].SubItems.Objects[2] := TObject(GetTickCount);
      ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i].SendText('ping' + #13#10);
    end;
  except
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

Before send, could be more appropriate check if the client is really connected or some like this. How make this? Thank's in advance.

Comment: You need to keep track of connects/disconnects per context. Add/remove list items as needed.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't recommend using such ancient components though. They only exist for backwards-compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to check for a connection.  If the client were actually disconnected, it would not be in the server's `Connections[]` list anymore when your `OnTimer` handler is triggered.  You should have an `OnClientDisconnect` handler assigned to the `TServerSocket` to remove the client from the `TListView`.

If, for some reason, the client were still in the `Connections[]` list (ie, because the underlying connection has been lost but `TServerSocket` hasn't detected it yet), then the socket would simply cache all outgoing data until its outbound buffer fills up, then it would start returning `WSAWOULDBLOCK` errors for each send. Eventually, the OS will timeout the dead connection and `TServerSocket` will remove it from the `Connections[]` list, triggering the `OnClientDisconnect` event.

At the very least, in the code you have shown, you should update your send loop to `Close()` any socket that actually fails to send, thus triggering the `OnClientDisconnect` event to remove that client from the `TListView`, eg:

```
procedure TMainForm.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Data := Socket;
  ...
end;

procedure TMainForm.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.FindData(0, Socket, True, False);
  if Item <> nil then
    Item.Delete;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  s: AnsiString = 'ping' + #13#10;
var
  Item: TListItem;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket;
  p: PAnsiChar;
  i, len, sent: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Item := ListView1.Items[i];
    Item.SubItems.Objects[2] := TObject(GetTickCount);
    Socket := TCustomWinSocket(Item.Data);
    try
      // SendText() does not handle partial sends, or Unicode strings...
      //Socket.SendText('ping' + #13#10);
      p := PAnsiChar(s);
      len := Length(s);
      repeat
        sent := Socket.SendBuf(p^, len);
        if sent = -1 then
        being
          if WSAGetLastError() <> WSAEWOULDBLOCK then
            Break;
          // TODO: stop trying after several attempts fail...
          Continue;
        end;
        Inc(p, sent);
        Dec(len, sent);
      until len = 0;
      if len = 0 then
        Continue;
    except
    end;
    Socket.Close;
  end;
end;
```